# Marketing Cloud - Decrypt File - "Secret key not found in key data"

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, decrypt

We have an integration that is sending a .pgp encrypted file to our Marketing Cloud FTP. Once the file is dropped into our /import folder, we are attempting to import and decrypt, it into Marketing Cloud via Automation, however we are running into an error that support has shared with us of "Secret key not found in key data".

1. We've generated a new PGP 4096-bit key pair using .ASC file format, and uploaded the Private Key into Key Management as the key type of Asymmetric.
2. In our Automation, during our File Transfer step to import from the FTP, we are running into an ambiguous error of "Secret key not found in key data"
3. When testing the decryption external to MC using the same private key, it decrypts the file successfully.

Edit: A new error was found by support:
Org.BouncyCastle.Bcpg.OpenPgp.PgpException: Checksum mismatch at 0 of 20 - from BouncyCastle.Crypto

Answer (score 1):

This was a passphrase issue. We had to remove some of the special characters we included in the passphrase and the decryption worked in the File Transfer step.